# Adding onclick() to link in drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal, google-analytics

I’m working in adding an `onclick` attribute to a few links on my drupal 7 site. I added the `menu_attributes` module to assign an id to my links, tried adding the following code to a new js file I included in `sites/themes/themeName.info`.

```
function() {
  var link = document.getElementById('conversion');
  //link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  link.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        return gtag_report_conversion('http://www.mysite/page’); }); }
```

It’s not adding onclick, would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the script is loading in the page. See  [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/adding-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module) for the details of adding javascript in drupal 7.

Comment: I included the 'Add to Head' module to add the other  .js scripts.  This one I've been trying to test it in developer console. I get the element but the error occurrs when trying to add "onclick()"

Comment: $('#conversation').on('click',function(){ //Code here } Could you try this?

Comment: I found this link, I think this is my issue, the script is looking for something not yet existing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element  .  Option 1 did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load) and adjusted for this specific problem this code works if placed inside head

```
function addClick(){
                    alert('click'); //confirm it works
                    return gtag_report_conversion('http://mySite/myPage');
                }

                 //make sure this runs after dom is loaded.. so element can be found
                 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
                    var link = document.getElementById("cteconversion");
                    link.onclick=addClick;
                 });
```